# Read a ANTLR grammar

Tags: java, antlr

Due a grammar, Antlr generates a parser.

However, I would need to issue the grammar itself.

For example, I would need to know how many rules are there, how many optional sub-rules are there, and so on.

For example,

```
Grammar grammar = read_stream ('grammar_file.g4).
for (Rule rule : grammar.getRules())
{
  //....
}
```

Does it exists something like this out of the box with ANTLR4?

Comment: Look for ANTLR-4 source files, they use an ANTLR grammar to parse ANTLR. I am not sure if it's ANTLR-2, ANTLR-3, or ANTLR-4, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.  See the documentation on [interpreted grammars](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/interpreters.md).  From a grammar file or string, you can create a [`Grammar` object](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/tool/src/org/antlr/v4/tool/Grammar.java), which has lots of methods you might be interested in, such as `getRule`.

Here's a quick example based on the documentation on that page (I haven't actually tested this!):

```
LexerGrammar lg = new LexerGrammar(
    "lexer grammar L;\n" +
    "A : 'a' ;\n" +
    "B : 'b' ;\n" +
    "C : 'c' ;\n");
Grammar g = new Grammar(
    "parser grammar T;\n" +
    "s : (A|B)* C ;\n",
    lg);

for (String ruleName : g.getRuleNames()) {
    Rule rule = g.getRule(null, ruleName);
    // ...
}
```

Note that the above does not include rules from imported grammars.  You can also get those via `getImportedGrammars`.